Netsh.exe application was unable to start correctly
I am having an pop-up of netsh.exe saying "The application was unable to start correctly 0xc0000142" whenever i reboot or shutdown my computer.
I have windows 11 pro operating system.
The problem started when i installed pycharm and i tried uninstalling it and again reboot it but the pop-up was still their
I have tried to update windows with repair option but the problem was still same
